# Not responding state during search in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, filter

I am creating a workbook that will copy and paste data from a source worksheet to multiple other worksheets depending upon values in a column. However, once I start the macro, Excel enters a not responding state. I am operating on anywhere from 4000 to 500,000 rows, but only 4 columns. When I only have ~4000 rows, it works pretty fast (3 seconds). When I have ~30,000 rows, Excel enters a not responding state for ~10 seconds, but then finishes. I didn't wait long enough for the 300,000 row test.

My thought process to do this would be to sort all of the data based upon the strings in column `B`, put all of column `B` (which contains the strings I am searching though) into an array, then pull all of the unique strings out into another array. For example, if column `B` held "Search" in rows 1-200, and "Create" in rows 201-500, the macro will search through the rows and the second array (lets call it Scenario) would end up holding two values, "Search" and "Create".

During the searching, I also created two parallel arrays that correspond with the Scenario array which would hold the beginning and ending rows for that scenario. After that, I would just loop through the values in the parallel arrays and copy/paste from the source worksheet to the other worksheets.

*NOTE:* The sort works fine

Is there a way to make this faster?

Here is the code:
Allocate Data

```
Sub AllocateData()

Dim scenarioRange As String             'To hold the composite range
Dim parallelScenarioName() As String    'Holds the unique scenario names
Dim parallelScenarioStart() As Long     'Holds the starting row of the scenario
Dim parallelScenarioEnd() As Long       'Holds the ending row of the scenario

Sheets("raw").Activate                  'Raw is the source worksheet

'Populates the parallel scenario arrays
Call GetScenarioList(parallelScenarioName, parallelScenarioStart, parallelScenarioEnd)

'Loops through the scenario parallel array and coes the copy and paste to other worksheets
'Workseets are named the same as the scenarios
For intPosition = LBound(parallelScenarioName) To (UBound(parallelScenarioName) - 1)
    scenarioRange = "A" & parallelScenarioStart(intPosition) & ":" & "D" & parallelScenarioEnd(intPosition)
    Range(scenarioRange).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Worksheets(parallelScenarioName(intPosition)).Activate

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("raw").Activate
Next

End Sub
```

GetScenarioList

```
Sub GetScenarioList(ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String, ByRef parallelScenarioStart() As Long, ByRef parallelScenarioEnd() As Long)
Dim scenarioName As Variant
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim arraySize As Long
arraySize = 1

'Prep the parallel array for scenario name with the first value
ReDim parallelScenarioStart(1)
ReDim parallelScenarioName(1)
parallelScenarioStart(0) = 1                'First spot on the scenario start will be row 1

'Prep the first scenario name
'Sometimes a number will be attached on the end of the scenario name delimited by a period. Ignore it.
If (InStr(Cells(1, 2).Text, ".") <> 0) Then
    parallelScenarioName(0) = Left(Cells(1, 2).Text, InStr(Cells(1, 2).Text, ".") - 1)
Else
    parallelScenarioName(0) = Cells(1, 2).Text
End If

'Get the total amount of rows
TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

'Loop through all of the rows
For i = 1 To TotalRows
    'Sometimes a number will be attached on the end of the scenario name delimited by a period. Ignore it.
    If (InStr(Cells(i, 2).Text, ".") <> 0) Then
        scenarioName = Left(Cells(i, 2).Text, InStr(Cells(i, 2).Text, ".") - 1)
    Else
        scenarioName = Cells(i, 2).Text
    End If

    'If the scenario name is not contained in the unique array
    If IsNotInArray(scenarioName, parallelScenarioName) Then
        Call AddScenarioEndRow(i, arraySize, parallelScenarioEnd)
        Call AddNewScenarioToParallelArray(scenarioName, arraySize, parallelScenarioName)
        Call AddNewScenarioStartRow(i, arraySize, parallelScenarioStart)
    End If
Next

'Cleanup. The above code did not cover the ending row of the last scenario
Call AddScenarioEndRow(TotalRows + 1, arraySize, parallelScenarioEnd)

End Sub
```

IsNotInArray

```
Function IsNotInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String) As Boolean
  IsNotInArray = Not (UBound(Filter(parallelScenarioName, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Parallel Arrays

```
Sub AddNewScenarioToParallelArray(str As Variant, arraySize As Long, ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String)
arraySize = UBound(parallelScenarioName) + 1
ReDim Preserve parallelScenarioName(arraySize)
parallelScenarioName(arraySize - 1) = str
End Sub

Sub AddScenarioEndRow(row As Variant, ByRef arraySize As Long, ByRef parallelScenarioEnd() As Long)
ReDim Preserve parallelScenarioEnd(arraySize)
parallelScenarioEnd(arraySize - 1) = row - 1
End Sub

Sub AddNewScenarioStartRow(row As Variant, ByRef arraySize As Long, ByRef parallelScenarioStart() As Long)
ReDim Preserve parallelScenarioStart(arraySize)
parallelScenarioStart(arraySize - 1) = row
End Sub
```

Comment: At least tell me why you chose to down-vote. Usually helps people to improve if they know why...

Comment: Unless you're going to be doing something else with those arrays, your code could be significantly simplified just by pre-sorting on ColB using a single sub.

Comment: I am doing that actually. ColB is sorted A-Z before it hits Allocate Data

Comment: How can I mark this question as obsolete? We ended up wanting metadata in a worksheet which gave me the list of scenarios to pull from instead of having to find them, which then allowed me to just do a .Find(string). I can now do ~500k rows in seconds.

Or, is it more appropriate to post the new code and mark it as solved?

Comment: You can post your "solution" as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My requirements ended up changing slightly. The QA lead wanted Metadata in the raw worksheet, so I had the full list of scenarios at my disposal instead of having to look at every row in the raw data. As a result, I could save and sort the scenario list to an array, and then do a .Find(parallelScenarioName(intPosition + 1)).row to get the row of the next scenario.

Because of this change, I did not fully implement and test Tim Williams solution which would iterate through every row in the data. I have to move on for now, but will revisit and test Tim's solution for my own knowledge soon.

The finished code is below.

```
'This is in a module so that my subs can see it
Option Explicit
Public Const DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET As String = "raw"

'This is the macro is called. Can be considered main.
Sub AllocateImportedData()
    Call SortDataSourceWorksheet
    Call AllocateData
End Sub

Sub SortDataSourceWorksheet()
    Dim entireRangeToSort As String
    Dim colToSortUpon As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = FindLastRowOfRawData
    entireRangeToSort = ConstructRangeString("A", 1, "D", lastRow)
    colToSortUpon = ConstructRangeString("B", 1, "B", lastRow)

    Call SortRangeByColumnAtoZ(entireRangeToSort, colToSortUpon)
End Sub

Sub SortRangeByColumnAtoZ(entireRangeToSort As String, colToSortUpon As String)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(colToSortUpon), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET).Sort
    .SetRange Range(entireRangeToSort)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With  
End Sub


Sub AllocateData()

    Dim scenarioRange As String             'To hold the composite range
    Dim parallelScenarioName() As String    'Holds the unique scenario names
    Dim parallelScenarioStart() As Long     'Holds the starting row of the scenario
    Dim parallelScenarioEnd() As Long       'Holds the ending row of the scenario

    Sheets(DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET).Activate

    Call PopulateParallelScenarioArrays(parallelScenarioName, parallelScenarioStart, parallelScenarioEnd)
    Call PerformAllocation(parallelScenarioName, parallelScenarioStart, parallelScenarioEnd)
    Call FinishByActivatingDesiredWorksheet(DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET)  
End Sub

Sub PerformAllocation(ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String, ByRef parallelScenarioStart() As Long, ByRef parallelScenarioEnd() As Long)

    For intPosition = LBound(parallelScenarioName) To (UBound(parallelScenarioName) - 1)
        scenarioRange = ConstructRangeString("A", parallelScenarioStart(intPosition), "D", parallelScenarioEnd(intPosition))
        Range(scenarioRange).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Worksheets(parallelScenarioName(intPosition)).Activate

        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets(DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET).Activate
    Next 
End Sub

Sub PopulateParallelScenarioArrays(ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String, ByRef parallelScenarioStart() As Long, ByRef parallelScenarioEnd() As Long)
    Dim numberOfScenarios As Long

    numberOfScenarios = GetScenarioListFromRaw(parallelScenarioName)
    ReDim parallelScenarioStart(numberOfScenarios)
    ReDim parallelScenarioEnd(numberOfScenarios)
    Call GetStartAndEndRows(parallelScenarioName, parallelScenarioStart, parallelScenarioEnd)   
End Sub

Function GetScenarioListFromRaw(ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String) As Long

    Dim numberOfScenarios As Long
    Dim scenarioRange As String
    Const scenarioListStartColumn As String = "F"
    Const scenarioListStartRow As Long = "3"

    numberOfScenarios = GetNumberOfScenarios(scenarioListStartColumn, scenarioListStartRow)

    ReDim parallelScenarioName(numberOfScenarios)

    'Populate parallel scenario name
    For i = 0 To (numberOfScenarios - 1)
        scenarioRange = scenarioListStartColumn & (scenarioListStartRow + i)
        parallelScenarioName(i) = Range(scenarioRange).Text
    Next

    Call AtoZBubbleSort(parallelScenarioName)

    GetScenarioListFromRaw = numberOfScenarios

End Function

Function GetNumberOfScenarios(scenarioListStartColumn As String, scenarioListStartRow As Long)
    GetNumberOfScenarios = Range(scenarioListStartColumn & scenarioListStartRow, Range(scenarioListStartColumn & scenarioListStartRow).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End Function


Sub GetStartAndEndRows(ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String, ByRef parallelScenarioStart() As Long, ByRef parallelScenarioEnd() As Long)
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim newScenarioRow As Long

    'Prep the parallel array for scenario name with the first value
    parallelScenarioStart(0) = 1                'First spot on the scenario start will be row 1

    'Get the total amount of rows
    TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For intPosition = LBound(parallelScenarioName) To (UBound(parallelScenarioName) - 1)
        'Find the row of the next scenario
        newScenarioRow = Worksheets(DATASOURCE_WORKSHEET).Columns(2).Find(parallelScenarioName(intPosition + 1)).row

        'Next scenario row - 1 is going to be the end of the current row
        parallelScenarioEnd(intPosition) = newScenarioRow - 1

        'Set starting row of next scenario
        parallelScenarioStart(intPosition + 1) = newScenarioRow
    Next   
End Sub

Sub FinishByActivatingDesiredWorksheet(desiredWorksheet As String)
    Sheets(desiredWorksheet).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub AtoZBubbleSort(ByRef parallelScenarioName() As String)

    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = LBound(parallelScenarioName) To UBound(parallelScenarioName)
        For j = i To UBound(parallelScenarioName)
            If UCase(parallelScenarioName(j)) < UCase(parallelScenarioName(i)) Then
                s1 = parallelScenarioName(j)
                s2 = parallelScenarioName(i)
                parallelScenarioName(i) = s2
                parallelScenarioName(j) = s1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub ClearWorkbookCells()
    Dim anyWS As Worksheet

    For Each anyWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call ClearWorksheetCells(anyWS)
    Next    
End Sub

Sub ClearWorksheetCells(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Activate

    ' Find the last row and create range var
    lastRow = FindLastRowOfRawData
    ClearRange = "A1:" & "D" & lastRow

    'Select the area to clear and perform clear
    ActiveSheet.Range(ClearRange).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub

Function FindLastRowOfRawData()
    FindLastRowOfRawData = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
End Function

Function ConstructRangeString(startCol As String, startRow As Long, endCol As String, endRow As Long) As String
    ConstructRangeString = startCol & startRow & ":" & endCol & endRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work on unsorted data, but will be much faster if you sort first.

```
Sub AllocateData()

    Dim shtRaw As Worksheet, currVal, rng As Range
    Dim c As Range, rngCopy As Range, i As Long, tmp

    Set shtRaw = Sheets("raw")

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rng = shtRaw.Range(shtRaw.Range("B1"), _
                           shtRaw.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    currVal = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" 'or any non-value

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        tmp = c.Value
        If tmp <> currVal Then
            If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                rngCopy.Copy Sheets(currVal).Cells(Rows.Count, _
                                       "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            Set rngCopy = c.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 4)
            currVal = tmp
            i = 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
            Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Resize(i, 4)
        End If
    Next c

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rngCopy.Copy Sheets(currVal).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

haveError:
    'must reset calculation, or it will remain on "manual"
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    'ScreenUpdating will auto-reset once the sub exits,
    '   but I think it's good practise to explicitly reset it
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately Application.ScreenUpdating had no effect on the performance. I also realized that the time it takes as a function of the row count is not linear. I made some changes and now it takes ~5 seconds for 20k rows, and ~15 seconds for 40k rows. Now that I know those changes didn't help enough, I will be looking at your solution and possibly implementing today.

Answer (score 1):

Copy-paste is, in my expreience, the slowest thing you can do in VBA.
Try simply assigning the values of range 1 to range 2, kinda like this:

```
range("b1:b4").value=range("a1:a4").value
```

Make sure the ranges are of the same size.

In your AllocateData sub, you could use something like:

```
Worksheets(parallelScenarioName(intPosition)).activate
Range(cells(1,1),cells(scenariorange.rows.count,1).value=scenariorange.value
Sheets("raw").Activate
```

Oh, I have changed scenariorange to be a range variable, lot easier to use in my opinion. Use it like this:

```
Dim ScenarioRange as Range
Set ScenarioRange = Range("A" & parallelScenarioStart(intPosition) & ":" & "D" & parallelScenarioEnd(intPosition))
```

Hope this speeds things up. (And I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say here, I'm a bit sleepy... :) )

Also, turning off the screenupdating usually speeds up the program a lot.

```
application.screenupdating=false
```

Don't forget to turn it back on at the end of the code!

Comment: Setting `Application.Calculation` to manual while running your code will also improve performance.  Again - don't forget to reset it when you're done.

Comment: Unfortunately Application.Calculation had no effect on the performance. Also, it isn't copy + paste that make it take a while. I tested that on 20k and 40k rows--it takes one section to do the copy + paste part no matter how many rows are effected. It's the "GetScenarioList" function that takes all of the time.

Comment: Eh, takes one second*